# How do I access a parent directive variable?

Tags: angularjs

How do I access a parent directive's variable? I keep getting undefined.

I'm trying to access from productName to productTitle. Running angular 1.6

```
  angular.module('appStore').controller(
    'TestController', function($scope, Note){    
      $scope.yell = function(){
        return Note(5);
      };
    }
  );

  angular.module('appStore').directive('productTitle', function(){
    return {
      restrict : 'E',
      templateUrl : 'product-title.html',
      scope : {
        age : '='
      },
      controller : function($scope){
          $scope.name = "mary";
      },
      link : function(scope, element, attrs){
      }
    };
  });

  angular.module('appStore').directive('productName', function(){
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      templateUrl: 'product-name.html',
      require: '^productTitle',
      link : function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl){
    console.log('test');
        console.log(ctrl.name); // undefined???
        console.log(ctrl.age);  // undefined???
      },
      transclude: true

    };
  });
```

index.html:

```
<div ng-controller="TestController">
  <product-title age="6"></product-title>
</div>
```

product-title.html

```
<h3>Product Titles</h3>
<product-name></product-name>
```

product-name is blank.

Comment: Thanks for updating, I'm guessing a bit here but can you set `transclude: false` and `scope: false` in `productName` to fix this?

Comment: Just tried it, nothing happened.. If I do console.log(ctrl), I just get constructor()

Comment: oh wow...  i had to change $scope.name = "mary" to  this.name = "mary" to get it to work.

Comment: Yes, was just going to say that.

Comment: There's a [similar example here](https://www.undefinednull.com/2014/07/07/practical-guide-to-prelink-postlink-and-controller-methods-of-angular-directives/) which you may have already seen.